# Linkbutton Text From Previouspage

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I have a gridview with a linkbutton that is posting crosspage when a value in the ID column is clicked. I want the ID to be posted to the next page so that it cant be seen in the url. (no querystring) The gridview is contained within a contentplaceholder. I would like to know how to response.write the linkbuttons (lbID) text on details.aspx using findcontrol. Please help. (Im using VB, I should have mentioned that.)

```
    <asp:Content ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="gvOpen" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="Black" Width="96%" DataKeyNames="id" 
    DataSourceID="Open" CssClass="Grid" AllowPaging="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFCC" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="priority" HeaderText="Priority">
    <ItemStyle Height="28px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="28px" />                                            
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbID" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/details.aspx"> <%# Eval("ID") %></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want: [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode_4a1baf2f-27e3-422e-a5a9-936e7653376d)

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton lbID = (LinkButton) PreviousPage.FindControl("lbID");
   string linkText = "";

   if(lbID != null)
     linkText = lbID.Text;
}
```

You might want to set linkButton text like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbID" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/details.aspx" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried this? To my knowledge, `PreviousPage` works with server transfers, and can't be used like this.

Comment: That example was copied from MSDN and I provided the link in the answer, so the idea is not really mine

Comment: Tried it out, and it works fine. Thanks, I learned something new.

Comment: Well, I had the impression that it should work. This is why - the default postback post to the same page and you access the information (e.g. controls) from codebehind. With this, the postback is to another page and those information are posted to the new page instead of the page in which they occur. Thanks for trying it out. :)

Comment: Im using VB but i was able to convert. When i use this code, nothing happens. Page loads but i cant response.write linktext. If I remove the "if lbID is not nothing" i get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Any ideas?      -PS: I did make the change in my markup so Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' as you suggested.